# Itterate and find ChoiceType in glue DynamicFrame

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a dyanmic dataframe which consists of ChoiceType

```
file = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(...)
```

As the structure is fairly dynamic I want to find the key where ChoiceType occurs
How should I do that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you could do:

```python
from typing import List

from awsglue.gluetypes import ChoiceType, Field, StructType, ArrayType, NullType


def check_for_unresolved_fields(schema: List[Field]):
    def _recursion(field_map: List[Field], unresolved_column_names: List[Field]):
        for field in field_map.values():
            if isinstance(field.dataType, StructType):
                _recursion(field.dataType.field_map, unresolved_column_names)
            if isinstance(field.dataType, ArrayType):
                if not isinstance(field.dataType.elementType, NullType):
                    if isinstance(field.dataType.elementType, StructType):
                        _recursion(field.dataType.elementType.field_map, unresolved_column_names)
                    if isinstance(field.dataType.elementType, ChoiceType):
                        unresolved_column_names.append((field.name, field.dataType.elementType.choices))
            if isinstance(field.dataType, ChoiceType):
                unresolved_column_names.append((field.name, field.dataType.choices))

    unresolved_columns = []
    _recursion(schema.field_map, unresolved_columns)
    if unresolved_columns:
        raise ValueError(f'The following columns {unresolved_columns} are still not resolved')

check_for_unresolved_fields(dynamic_frame.schema())
```